# Rshell on windows freezes randomly while sending files to ESP32 running micropython via rsync or cp

Tags: windows, esp32, micropython

I'm having trouble copying files to ESP32 device running micropython via rshell (remote micropython shell). The problem seems to occur randomly. Sometimes I manage to successfuly send all files (like 20 of them) with `rsync` and sometimes I cannot even copy one file with `cp`. There is no error message and script doesn't crash, it just stops working and freezes the console. I've tried with and without -a parameter (I'm sending only .py files). The last thing printed with debug is code to be run on microcontroller below and it just stops there. I didn't find any pattern. I've tried using some other esp32 device and other windows PC. Same results. I even tried lowering default 32 buffer to 16, no improvement. The worst thing is that is sometimes works fine and I cannot get constant results (even bad). It stops on random files, not always the same one.

Rsync command (with --mirror parameter) is very helpful and I could not just copy all files by hand.

EDIT: just tested on mac and it works fine. I guess it's just problem on windows...

```
Adding /pyboard/protocol/parser.py
----- About to send 2269 bytes of code to the pyboard -----
def recv_file_from_host(src_file, dst_filename, filesize, dst_mode='wb'):
"""Function which runs on the pyboard. Matches up with send_file_to_remote."""
import sys
import ubinascii
import os
if False:
    try:
        import pyb
        usb = pyb.USB_VCP()
    except:
        try:
            import machine
            usb = machine.USB_VCP()
        except:
            usb = None
    if usb and usb.isconnected():
        # We don't want 0x03 bytes in the data to be interpreted as a Control-C
        # This gets reset each time the REPL runs a line, so we don't need to
        # worry about resetting it ourselves
        usb.setinterrupt(-1)
try:
    with open(dst_filename, dst_mode) as dst_file:
        bytes_remaining = filesize
        if not False:
            bytes_remaining *= 2  # hexlify makes each byte into 2
        buf_size = 32
        write_buf = bytearray(buf_size)
        read_buf = bytearray(buf_size)
        while bytes_remaining > 0:
            # Send back an ack as a form of flow control
            sys.stdout.write('\x06')
            read_size = min(bytes_remaining, buf_size)
            buf_remaining = read_size
            buf_index = 0
            while buf_remaining > 0:
                if False:
                    bytes_read = sys.stdin.buffer.readinto(read_buf, read_size)
                else:
                    bytes_read = sys.stdin.readinto(read_buf, read_size)
                if bytes_read > 0:
                    write_buf[buf_index:bytes_read] = read_buf[0:bytes_read]
                    buf_index += bytes_read
                    buf_remaining -= bytes_read
            if False:
                dst_file.write(write_buf[0:read_size])
            else:
                dst_file.write(ubinascii.unhexlify(write_buf[0:read_size]))
            if hasattr(os, 'sync'):
                os.sync()
            bytes_remaining -= read_size
    return True
except:
    return False
output = recv_file_from_host(None, '/protocol/parser.py', 1467)
if output is None:
print("None")
else:
print(output)

-----
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem , 
when trying

```
    C:\> cp src\main.py /pyboard/
```

the cmd freezes. 
When I copied using the following

```
    C:\> cp src/main.py /pyboard/
```

There where no issues, so maybe rshell has some problems when there are "\" in the path